# webGL texture not showed in rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I'm having problem texturing my rectangle where is displayed black canvas instead of textured canvas with image.

First I'm creating webGL program, attaching shaders and linking webGL program as usual.

Then I'm creating texture when image is loaded like this:

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Saint-Gervais-les-Bains_-_Mt-Blanc_JPG01.jpg";
image.onload = function() {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    // Upload the image into the texture.
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  }
```

After that I pass the information about rectangle verticies into the vertex shader:

```
var pos = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "pos");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(pos);
var pos_Buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pos_Buffer);
var vertices = [-1.0, -1.0, // "left-down"
  -1.0, 1.0, // "left-top"
  1.0, -1.0, // "right-down"
  1.0, 1.0, // "right-top"
];
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(pos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

And in the end I draw my rectangle by passing indexes of verticies into drawElements function:

```
var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
var indices = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3];
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint8Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
// draw triangles
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

[There](http://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/echsqkaw/4/) is a jsfiddle with my problem.
Please, don't you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have this locally or on a server (local server goes too)? If it's local, then do you have allow-cross-origin as true in your browser?

Comment: I see no error handling. Does glGetError return anything else than GL_NO_ERROR at the end of your program?

Comment: Have you tried opening the console? It usually has sime nice error information in it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is nothing in console and I have this image included by URL from some another server.

Comment: I included allow-cross-origin extension right now but nothing happend.

Comment: I would say it has something to do with the image. I just had a look at your fiddle and replaced the image with a canvas. Changed `image.src = "url"` to `image.src = textCanvas.toDataURL()` and then bound it (called onload manually). It showed up just fine so the problem could be the image is way to big and taking to long to load or out of GPU memory??  or you are not getting cross origin permission.

Comment: That is only on your side, there's a chance wikimedia doesn't allow http requests.

Comment: Oh no, I take it back, your image is in jpg, jp doesn't suppirt alpha, try to set the format as gl.RGB

Comment: @Blindman67 true, limitation is device dependent and safe value is 2048, which is larger then OPs target texture. Anyway there was more then one issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image.onload` is asynchronous function and you do draw call before the function is executed (image isn't loaded when you draw on canvas).

You must put `gl.drawElements` inside:

```
image.onload = function() { // image.onload STARTS
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    // Upload the image into the texture.
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);

    // anything you want, blehblahbleh ...

    // draw on canvas
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

} // image.onload ENDS
```

Also yes there was a problem with cross origin resource call, but I guess you solved it out with extension (or for jsfiddle tests you might use base64 format).

Slightly updated sample: http://jsfiddle.net/windkiller/6cLo3890/